# How to retrieve distinct items from Firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing an Android app and I need to retrieve all the distinct values of the field 'brand' from the Firebase Database given below. How do I do that?
[image: my firebase database]

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35177398/5545429

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way around was to create a new tree that solely stored distinct brands.

Answer (score 0):

I initiated Firebase functions and wrote a TypeScript function

> ```
>   db.collection('assignments').orderBy('subject')
>   .get().then(value => {
>    var subjects: string[] = [];
>    value.docs.forEach(doc =>{
>      const thisSubject = doc.data()['subject'];
>      console.log(thisSubject);
>   //here's where the filtering is
>      if (!subjects.includes(thisSubject)){
>                  subjects += thisSubject;
>      };
>  }
> );
> ```

That will at least get you to the array, then you can return the array to your Android app (or whatever you've initialized on Firebase).

Answer (score -1):

If you are a Kotlin user, You may do it

```js
fun <T> Array<out T>.distinct(): List<T>
fun ByteArray.distinct(): List<Byte>
fun ShortArray.distinct(): List<Short>
fun IntArray.distinct(): List<Int>
fun LongArray.distinct(): List<Long>
fun FloatArray.distinct(): List<Float>
fun DoubleArray.distinct(): List<Double>
fun BooleanArray.distinct(): List<Boolean>
fun CharArray.distinct(): List<Char>
```

reference : https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/distinct.html