# Query function for distinct result in firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any Query function to get the distinct result in firestore.

For example:

```
Query query = colRef.orderBy("title")
                        .startAt("R")
                        .limit(10);
```

This gives me all the documents with "title" starting with "R", which contain duplicates like this:

```
Recording
Running
Running
Running
```

How can I get a distinct result like this:

```
Recording
Running
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35170616/firebase-and-select-distinct

Comment: Not at all a duplicate - Firestore and Firebase Realtime Database (which the other post is asking about based on context) are not the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately there is no `distinct()` method within Cloud Firestore. Because you are ordering your data by `title`, which is a key within each child this is possible. To query your database and get only the distnict elements you need to come up with another solution which would be to create another node named `distinctTitles` in which you need to add all those titles. To avoid duplicate elements (overriding data), first you need to check for `uniqueness` using [exists()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#exists()) method like this:

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("distinctTitles").document("titleToCheck");
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.exists()) {
            //Do something
        } else {
            //Do something else
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You may explore firebase function for this, if you use firebase for multi platform it can be a better choice to implement this kind of function.