# If I have repeated documents in firestore, how can I receive only one? Flutter Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I create ToDo App using Flutter. I wnat to receive all todos from collection and sort them by timestamp, but I have todos with same timestamp and I want to receive length of docs inside collection without repeats

As you can see on picture from my app, when I add new task for today or tomorrow blocks with tasks repeated as many times as the tasks with the given time.

How can I receive all docs from Firestore collection if I have same docs, but want to receive length without same docs?

```
     StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection(uid)
                    .doc('toDos')
                    .collection('toDos')
                    .where('dateTime', isNotEqualTo: DateTime.now())
                    .orderBy('dateTime', descending: false)
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshots) {
                  if (snapshots.hasData) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: snapshots.data.docs.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshots =
                              snapshots.data.docs[index];
                       
                      

                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text(documentSnapshots['dateTime']
                                .toDate()
                                .toString()),
                            subtitle: Container(
                              color: Colors.redAccent,
                              child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                      .collection(uid)
                                      .doc('toDos')
                                      .collection('toDos')
                                      .orderBy('dateTime',
                                          descending: false)
                                      .snapshots(),
                                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                      return ListView.builder(
                                        physics:
                                            NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                        shrinkWrap: true,
                                        itemCount:
                                            snapshot.data.docs.length,
                                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                          DocumentSnapshot
                                              documentSnapshot =
                                              snapshot.data.docs[index];

                                          Timestamp timestamp =
                                              documentSnapshot['dateTime'];
                                          return Dismissible(
                                              background: Container(
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        BorderRadius
                                                            .circular(
                                                                12.0)),
                                                alignment:
                                                    Alignment.centerLeft,
                                                child: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                              ),
                                              onDismissed: (direction) =>
                                                  DatabaseService()
                                                      .deleteToDos(
                                                          documentSnapshot[
                                                              'todoTitle']),
                                              key: Key(documentSnapshot[
                                                  'todoTitle']),
                                              child:
                                                  documentSnapshot[
                                                              'dateTime'] ==
                                                          documentSnapshots[
                                                              'dateTime']
                                                      ? Card(
                                                          elevation: 0.7,
                                                          shape:
                                                              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                            borderRadius:
                                                                BorderRadius
                                                                    .circular(
                                                              12.0,
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
                                                          child: ListTile(
                                                            subtitle: Text(
                                                              ChooseLanguageState
                                                                      .enLang
                                                                  ? '\n' +
                                                                      dateEng
                                                                          .format(DateTime.tryParse(timestamp
                                                                              .toDate()
                                                                              .toString()))
                                                                          .toString()
                                                                  : '\n' +
                                                                      dateRu
                                                                          .format(DateTime.tryParse(timestamp.toDate().toString()))
                                                                          .toString(),
                                                              style:
                                                                  TextStyle(
                                                                fontFamily:
                                                                    'MontserratLight',
                                                                fontWeight:
                                                                    FontWeight
                                                                        .w200,
                                                                color: Colors
                                                                    .grey,
                                                                fontSize:
                                                                    sizeX.height /
                                                                        70,
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                            leading:
                                                                Padding(
                                                              padding: EdgeInsets
                                                                  .only(
                                                                      top:
                                                                          10,
                                                                      bottom:
                                                                          10),
                                                              child:
                                                                  IconButton(
                                                                onPressed:
                                                                    () async {
                                                                  setState(
                                                                      () {
                                                                    DatabaseService()
                                                                        .completeTask(documentSnapshot['todoTitle']);
                                                                  });
                                                                },
                                                                icon: documentSnapshot[
                                                                        'isComplete']
                                                                    ? SvgPicture
                                                                        .asset(
                                                                        'assets/icons/icon_done.svg',
                                                                      )
                                                                    : SvgPicture
                                                                        .asset(
                                                                        'assets/icons/icon_circle.svg',
                                                                        color:
                                                                            Colors.black,
                                                                      ),
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                            title: Text(
                                                              documentSnapshot[
                                                                  'todoTitle'],
                                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                                  fontFamily:
                                                                      'MontserratLight',
                                                                  fontWeight:
                                                                      FontWeight
                                                                          .w700,
                                                                  color: Colors
                                                                      .black),
                                                            ),
                                                            trailing:
                                                                IconButton(
                                                                    onPressed:
                                                                        () {
                                                                      setState(
                                                                          () {
                                                                        DatabaseService().deleteToDos(documentSnapshot['todoTitle']);
                                                                      });
                                                                    },
                                                                    icon: SvgPicture
                                                                        .asset(
                                                                      'assets/icons/icon_trash.svg',
                                                                      color:
                                                                          Colors.redAccent,
                                                                    )),
                                                          ),
                                                        )
                                                      : null);
                                        },
                                      );
                                    } else if (snapshots.hasError) {
                                      const Text('No Data');
                                    }
                                    return Center(
                                        child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                                  }),
                            ),
                          );
                        });
                  } else if (snapshots.hasError) {
                    const Text('No Data');
                  }
                  return Center(
                    child: Container(),
                  );
                },
              ),
```

[firestore picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwxbD.jpg)

[app picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRoCT.jpg)

Comment: after you get data from firestore. store it into a Set() and then  convert set to list by calling toList() on set

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you give me any example, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query function for distinct result in firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47862798/query-function-for-distinct-result-in-firestore)

Comment: @JanHernandez not sure, but i'm going to try, thanks!